# How to read .mat files in EEGLab?

Tags: matlab, dataset, seed, eeglab

I am trying to read SEED Dataset in EEGLAB. The files are in .mat format. I am getting the error as --- EEGLAB error in function pop_loadeeg() at line124.Output argument "accept" and maybe others not assigned during call to "F:eeglab2019\plugins\neuroscanio1.3\loadeeg.m>loadeeg".

How to read the .mat file of EEG SEED Dataset in EEGLAB ? Please guide.

Comment: Please copy the code!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help:

Run eeglab.m, next in the pop up window:  file->import data -> using EEGLAB functions and plugins -> from ASCII/float file or Matlab array.

Almost you can check the tutorial in the official EEGLAB page.
https://sccn.ucsd.edu/wiki/A01:_Importing_Continuous_and_Epoched_Data